# Best free program to view 3D models in Collada format?

Tags: software-recommendation, 3d

I'm working on a software project which requires some 3D models. We hired a freelance modeler and she just delivered the first model in Collada format.

For now, I just want to see what it looks like (rendering will come later). I have tried:

### Collada import plugin for Caligari trueSpace, by "Clintonman"

This one never worked. I followed the instructions for installation, but when I try to use it, it pops up an error message. Googling for the message didn't come up with anything.

### Ballistic3D Collada model viewer

I can run this one, but when I open up the model, nothing appears. No errors or anything appear in the application log.

### colladaAirViewer, by Anthony Scavarelli

I was able to install and run this one. When I try to load the model, it starts churning away, using 100% of CPU and 500MB of memory, but after 15 minutes, the model still doesn't appear.

colladaAirViewer is telling me that the model has 143104 triangles. Is it strange to have such a large number? Perhaps this is why it is taking so long to draw.

Can anyone recommend a better (free) model viewer, which works with Collada files?

Comment: What's wrong with this question? I don't think it should be voted down

Comment: "Technical questions related to 3D software" are off-topic [per the FAQ](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/faq#questions).

Answer (score 4):

Try blender

It apparently support natively Collada

[blender](http://www.blender.org)

Comment: Thanks. I was going to try Blender, but someone I am working with tried it first and it crashed when trying to import a Collada model.

Comment: But +1 for posting this information...

Comment: I would try myself if I were you, Blender is quick to install! ;)

Comment: Yes, Blender is pretty quick to install, it is about 32megas. And the best, it is not ugly anymore (since 2.5)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use [Google Sketchup](http://sketchup.google.com/intl/en/product/newin7.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vanda Engine RTI as well. It has a 30 days free trial version. It imports most of the elements of COLLADA files and lets you convert your scene to real time interactive scene. Here's their website:
[www.vandaengine.com](http://www.vandaengine.com)